# Kubernetes cluster autoscaler does not seem to work on GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've got a node pool defined with min instances set to 1 and max instances set to 5, and autoscaling enabled.

However it does not seem to be scaling down.

- I have cordoned a node.
- It has been over 12 hours
- There are no pending pods
- Removing a node would not reduce the amount of replicas of my own deployment

The node in question has the following pods running on it:

- fluentd
- kube-dns
- kube-proxy-gke
- metrics-server
- redis

All the pods above are in the `kube-system` namespace besides the `redis` pod which is defined within a daemonset.

Is there any additional configuration required? A pod disruption budget perhaps?

Output of `kubectl describe -n kube-system configmap cluster-autoscaler-status`:

```
Name:         cluster-autoscaler-status
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/last-updated=2018-06-15 10:40:16.289611397 +0000 UTC

Data
====
status:
----
Cluster-autoscaler status at 2018-06-15 10:40:16.289611397 +0000 UTC:
Cluster-wide:
  Health:      Healthy (ready=4 unready=0 notStarted=0 longNotStarted=0 registered=4 longUnregistered=0)
               LastProbeTime:      2018-06-15 10:40:14.942263061 +0000 UTC
               LastTransitionTime: 2018-06-15 09:17:56.845900388 +0000 UTC
  ScaleUp:     NoActivity (ready=4 registered=4)
               LastProbeTime:      2018-06-15 10:40:14.942263061 +0000 UTC
               LastTransitionTime: 2018-06-15 09:18:55.777577792 +0000 UTC
  ScaleDown:   NoCandidates (candidates=0)
               LastProbeTime:      2018-06-15 10:40:14.942263061 +0000 UTC
               LastTransitionTime: 2018-06-15 09:39:03.33504599 +0000 UTC

NodeGroups:
  Name:        https://content.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/gcpwp-ayurved-subs-staging/zones/europe-west1-b/instanceGroups/gke-wordpress-preempt-nodes-9c33afcb-grp
  Health:      Healthy (ready=3 unready=0 notStarted=0 longNotStarted=0 registered=3 longUnregistered=0 cloudProviderTarget=3 (minSize=2, maxSize=3))
               LastProbeTime:      2018-06-15 10:40:14.942263061 +0000 UTC
               LastTransitionTime: 2018-06-15 09:17:56.845900388 +0000 UTC
  ScaleUp:     NoActivity (ready=3 cloudProviderTarget=3)
               LastProbeTime:      2018-06-15 10:40:14.942263061 +0000 UTC
               LastTransitionTime: 2018-06-15 09:18:55.777577792 +0000 UTC
  ScaleDown:   NoCandidates (candidates=0)
               LastProbeTime:      2018-06-15 10:40:14.942263061 +0000 UTC
               LastTransitionTime: 2018-06-15 09:39:03.33504599 +0000 UTC


Events:  <none>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cluster autoscaler not downscaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679188/cluster-autoscaler-not-downscaling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few constraints that could prevent the node from scaling down.

You should verify the pods you listed one by one against the [What types of pods can prevent CA from removing a node?](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/cluster-autoscaler-1.2.2/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node) documentation.
This should help you discover if there is a pod that prevents it.

If it is indeed the `redis` pod then you could try using the safe to evict annotation:

```
"cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "true"
```

If it is one of the system pods I would try the same thing on other nodes to see if scaling down works on them.
According to the [GKE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#minimum_and_maximum_node_pool_size), you should be able to scale down your cluster to 1 node per cluster or completely for a specific node pool.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issues are the metric-server and the kube-dns. There are details at the [GKE autoscaler FAQ](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node). The short answer is that it is not recommended to make the metrics-server evictable. You can make the kube-dns evictable (details [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node)).

As to your specific question, I think you need to `kubectl drain` the node (that command also cordons if the node is not already cordoned).

Answer (score -1):

Also as stated in [GKE FAQ](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-does-scale-down-work), a node will not be downscaled until `the sum of cpu and memory requests of all pods running on this node is smaller than 50% of the node's allocatable.` See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679188/cluster-autoscaler-not-downscaling) for a duplicate question.